# How do I put multiple dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have created a dictionary:

```
new_list = {}
```

which gives,

```
    {'date': '13/09/2020', 'day': '13', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '35', 'deaths': '0', 
    'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 
    'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.3090878'}
    {'date': '12/9/20', 'day': '12', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '34', 'deaths': '0', 
    'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 
    'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.22496971'}
    {'date': '11/9/20', 'day': '11', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '28', 'deaths': '0', 
    'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 
    'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.16450983'}
```

But now I want to add this dictionary to a list

```
dataset= [new_list]
```

which gives,

```
[{'date': '13/09/2020', 'day': '13', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '35', 'deaths': '0', 'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.3090878'}]
[{'date': '12/9/20', 'day': '12', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '34', 'deaths': '0', 'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.22496971'}]
[{'date': '11/9/20', 'day': '11', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '28', 'deaths': '0', 'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.16450983'}]
```

However I am trying to get the outcome as (so only "[]" at the begin and the end), because then I can do dataset[0:2](otherwise it will give me 'Nonetype' object is not subscriptable) and it will only give the first two dictionaries

```
[{'date': '13/09/2020', 'day': '13', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '35', 'deaths': '0', 'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.3090878'},
{'date': '12/9/20', 'day': '12', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '34', 'deaths': '0', 'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.22496971'},
{'date': '11/9/20', 'day': '11', 'month': '9', 'year': '2020', 'cases': '28', 'deaths': '0', 'countriesAndTerritories': 'Afghanistan', 'countryTerritoryId': 'AF', 'countryTerritoryCode': 'AFG', 'population2019': '38041757', 'continent': 'Asia', 'cumulativeper1000002Weeks': '1.16450983'}]
```

My code is as follows:

```
import csv
def read_dataset() -> List[Dict[str,str]]:
    dataset = []
    with open('covid-19.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        no_head = next(reader, None)
       
        for row in reader:
            lst = [
                'date',
                'day', 
                'month', 
                'year',
                'cases', 
                'deaths', 
                'countriesAndTerritories', 
                'countryTerritoryId', 
                'countryTerritoryCode', 
                'population2019', 
                'continent',
                'cumulativeper1000002Weeks',
            ]
            new_list = {}
            for x in range(len(lst)):
                new_list[lst[x]] = row[x]
            dataset= [new_list]
            #print(dataset)
            
dataset = read_dataset()
print(dataset[0:2])
```

Comment: The same way that you would put multiple of *anything else* into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv
def read_dataset() -> List[Dict[str,str]]:
    dataset = []
    with open('covid-19.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        no_head = next(reader, None)
    
        for row in reader:
            lst = [
                'date',
                'day', 
                'month', 
                'year',
                'cases', 
                'deaths', 
                'countriesAndTerritories', 
                'countryTerritoryId', 
                'countryTerritoryCode', 
                'population2019', 
                'continent',
                'cumulativeper1000002Weeks',
            ]
            new_list = {}
            for x in range(len(lst)):
                new_list[lst[x]] = row[x]
            dataset.append(new_list)
            #print(dataset)
    return dataset
            
dataset = read_dataset()
print(dataset[0:2])
```

The difference is that you have to use the:

```
dataset.append(new_list)
```

functon, which append at the end the new_list (which is a dict, a little bit confusing, pay attention to the variable names!)

Comment: I know, I reused the code of @Bows to make it clearer for him.

Comment: It'll be good to correct naming and explain why you've done it in answer.

Comment: You can use `dict()` with `zip()` to replace `for` loop: `dict(zip(lst, row[:len(lst)]))`

Comment: Yea, the naming was my bad, should have paid more attention. The new list does work, however print(dataset[0:2]) gives  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable and I'm not sure how to fix that. Edit: I should have used return, thanks for the answers

Comment: You miss the return statement, I add it in the answer!